# SQL Server 2012 Agent SSIS Job Succeeds with Project Config to Environment Broken

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssdt-bi

This sounds similar to [SSIS package SQL job not using new environment variable configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442207/ssis-package-sql-job-not-using-new-environment-variable-configuration), but when I did a test on my dev SQL Server box, I didn't have to restart the SQL Server agent. And honestly, if that is what it takes to prevent someone from 'hurting' themselves with this product, then. . . that is absolutely unacceptable.

> UPDATE: And now, to follow up on that comment about [SSIS package SQL
>   job not using new environment variable configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442207/ssis-package-sql-job-not-using-new-environment-variable-configuration) possibly
>   being a solution.
>
> It is not. I restarted the agent. No dice. Job still runs
>   successfully. I restarted the SQL Server Agent and Service. Again, no
>   failure.
>
> This also sounds peripherally related to [SSIS 2012 SQL Agent Job
>   ConnectionString vs InitialCatalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125854/ssis-2012-sql-agent-job-connectionstring-vs-initialcatalog), but I've been working with SSIS
>   since 2005 and have never seen a connection string configure from it's
>   individual components. We have ALWAYS put the connecting string in the
>   .config files and had success.

I've got a problem that I haven't been able to resolve. Appears to be a bug, honestly, but I don't want to be so presumptuous.

I'm running SQL Server 2012 SP3 on Windows Server 2012 R2 in my test environment.

On my dev box, I'm running VS2012 + SSDT-BI.

I built a solution with a single SSIS 2012 project.

- I deployed the SSIS Project to my Test SQL Server box.
- I configured a new Environment (let's call it Fred).
- I add variables to the Fred environment.
- Some of these variables are connection strings.
- I go back to the SSIS Project in the SSISDB tree. Right-click and configure.
- I set all of my project's connection manager's connection string properties (only) to configure from one of Fred's connection string variables.

Now I have everything, connection-wise at least, wired to configure from my Fred Environment.

- I created a SQL Server Agent job (of type SSIS) to execute a package.
- I check the box to say Configure from environment .\Fred
- I complete job configuration.
- I right-click the job and choose 'Start Job at Step. . .'

The job executes. Yay! Everything works. Packages all execute. (Everyone is doing the dance of joy!)

**Now here comes the part I can't resolve.**

As part of my system testing (I'm new and cautious to the 2012+ Project Deployment model) I change a connection string value stored in one of my Fred Environment variables. This connection string was one that my SSIS project's connection manager's connection string (I triple-checked this) was configured to use.

The connection string is now invalid/incomplete and, now if I was to execute the same SQL Agent Job, the expectation is that the executed Package should fail (validation), right?

Well guess what. ***The job succeeds.*** (Dance of joy stops.) The packages all execute successfully. I check my test database environment and rows have been added to a table in a DB whose connection string is completed wrong (in the Fred environment).

So, now I think hmm, well, maybe I missed something. I go back in and I delete the environment variable that contains the invalid/incomplete connection string.

I execute the job again. Job succeeds. Uh, What?

- I launch my dev instance of SQL Server 2012 (RTM, not SP3, incidentally)
- I deploy a test project with the same project connection manager/environment configuration mapping
- I go through the same steps. . .

BUT now this time, the job fails as expected. Note: No SQL Server agent restart made/required.

- I go back to my Test box
- I right click the SQL Agent (SSIS) job
- I go to Properties > Steps (page) > Edit (first step. There's only one), and now I'm seeing the warning:

> The parameter "SomeOtherSSISProjectParameter" is configured to use an
>   environment variable, but no environment variable has been selected.
>   Check the "Environment" checkbox and specify the environment to use,
>   or specify a literal value for the parameter.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls)

Uh, what!?

- First off, the Environment check box in this job step is already checked.
- Secondly, this parameter is not related or mapped to the the Fred enviro. variable that I changed and then removed.
- Thirdly the Environment variable value is not null or empty. It's still there, un-touched from when I first added it to the environment.

(At this point, I'm thinking the SSISDB is corrupt.)

I click passed the warning. Now that I am here in the SSIS Package SQL Server Agent config page, as I try to click OK (without making any changes) I NOW get an expected error message related to the orphaned Environment config.

> Property "ConnectionString" of connection manager
>   "MySSISProjConnManagerName" is configured to receive a value from an
>   environment variable named "MyFredEnviroVariableName" but there is not
>   environment variable named "MyFredEnviroVariableName" in environment
>   ".\Fred". Select a different environment, or use a literal value for
>   the property.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls)

So the good news is that I can't click OK to save this corrupt job/step, but the bad news is that I CAN click cancel, and I can right click the job and choose 'Start Job at Step. . .' and have it complete successfully when it absolutely shouldn't.

Yes, I restarted the agent. Yes, I restarted to server.

I tested the scenario on my dev instance (RTM) of SQL Server 2012, and I can't reproduce it. Can anyone else? Better yet, is there a fix solution? SP4?

Any help with this would be MUCH appreciated. As far as I'm concerned this is a show-stopper for using the Project Deployment model with 2012.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with this specific problem, but you should be using VS 2010 to produce SSIS packages for use on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Well I know that SQL 2012 ships with the VS2010 shell as part of the SSDT+BI default build-out, but I didn't know I couldn't use VS2012 to talk to SQL Server 2012. Hmm. Will have to check on that.

Comment: See my answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086849/can-a-ssis-2012-package-be-deployed-to-sql-server-2008-r2  But basically, VS 2012 will create a xmla file that SQL 2012 can import, but there's no guarantee it will work as expected.

Comment: I'm revoking my answer (version compatability), although we are going to move to 2014 regardless. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx) states that you can deploy from SSDT+BI 2012 to SQL Server 2014, 2012, 2008 R2, and 2008. [This MSDN page I posted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577(v=sql.120).aspx) in my (now deleted) comment, also shows that, for Interoperability, SSDT+BI in VS 2012 can be used to deploy to SQL Server 2012.